# Getting zip and non-zipped files from ftp site via Azure Data Factory - unzipping

Tags: azure, unzip, azure-data-factory

I am successfully getting files from an ftp site via Azure Data Factory and unzipping them in the process. I am setting the source dataset for ZipDeflate. However, now I have a similar pipeline where I have to get files from an ftp site where there are a mix of .zip files and other file types like .csv and .xls.

When I try to do ZipDeflate on that Copy activity, it wants to "deflate" all of the files (not just the .zip). I kind of expected that . I'm thinking the only want to unzip only the .zip files and NOT unzip the .xls and .csv files is to do them in separate Copy activities (one for files needing unzipping and one for all others)....Is this right or is there another way to do it all in the one activity?

Thanks!!
J

Answer (score 1):

Well yes. You need to have two copy activities. But in that case, you will have two source dataset with different file filter I guess. (one for .zip, and seccond for all others) 
Something that came to my mind is to use metadata activity to take file name. After that, in IF condition you check if the file name contains ".zip", you proceed to activity for unzipping, and if false you continue to activity without unzipping. This way you use only one dataset that will collect all files, not to have separately. 
Hope this can work and help you. :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was thinking, but I didn't think about that metadata option! That would probably would work, too. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, with this you can reuse one source dataset. No problemo. If this was helpful in any way don't forget to upvote answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For the moment you could use the GetMetadata+Filter activities to split the files by types and create a separate copy activities for them. Or you could parameterize the dataset, and pass there Zip method like "ZipDeflate" or 'None' based on the extension of the file.

If we are talking not only about the native mechanics, you could create a custom .Net activity and create anything you want.